# Lists Splitting Equal Split

Tags: python-3.x, list

I wrote a code that takes a certain input (int) and stores it to a list.

The next phase, which I can't manage to construct is to take the list and split it to 4 equal lists.

So far I take the sum of the `prime_list` and divide it to 4. the sum stored as var to further use.

`prime_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]` split to equal 4 lists, divide by range (or other methods):

```
split_list_01 = [1,2,3]

split_list_02 = [4,5,6]

split_list_03 = [7,8,9]

split_list_04 = [10,11,12]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
prime_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
new_list = [prime_list[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(prime_list), 3)]
print new_list
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

---

A dictionary can be used to store each of the lists using different keys which can be accessed later:

```
prime_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

split_list = {}
count = 0
for i in range(0, len(prime_list), 3):
    split_list[count] = prime_list[i:i+3]
    count += 1
```

print split_list

**Output:**

```
{0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5, 6], 2: [7, 8, 9], 3: [10, 11, 12]}
```

Comment: It works, but how can I store each section to a new list var (4 lists total)?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. One way could be that you can use a dict to store the split list and access it appropriately.